# MVC - Kendo Template Giving Error When Using with special language characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

on my MVc project there are some language resource(.resx) files.Trying to pass  strings values to kendo template.If value has some special characters like 'ç' , 'ş' etc... it gives an error:

Html- Razor:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ListView<AIS.UI.WebService.Proxy.DSrvAllService.CaseListItemModel>()
            .Name("listView")
            .TagName("div")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "padding-left:15px" })
            .ClientTemplateId("template")
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Model(model => model.Id("CASEID"))
            .PageSize(5)
            .Events(events => events.Error("onError"))
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetListCases", "Case"))
               )
            .Pageable()
            .Editable()
         )


  <script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template" >
  <span>@CaseList.elapsed</span>
```

Error:

```
        Uncaught Error: Invalid template:'
```

Value of elapsed contains 'ç' character so getting error.

Answer (score 3):

using with @Html.Raw() fixed the poblem.Like this:

```
  <span>@Html.Raw(@CaseList.elapsed)</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check what is your browser receiving as template? Try also defining the template with no field (just this `@CaseList.elapsed`) and see if it works.

KendoUI Templates support characters as `ç` as you can see in here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/XNcmt/43/

```
<div id="data"></div>
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template" >
    <div>This is a literal: <span class="ob-literal">If value has some special characters like 'ç' , 'ş' etc... it gives an error</span></div>
    <div>This is actually a variable bound to the template: <span class="ob-value">#= text #</span></div>
</script>


var template = kendo.template($("#template").html());
var data = { text: "If value has some special characters like 'ç' , 'ş' etc... it gives an error" }; 
$("#data").html(template(data));
```

Comment: It works well(@CaseList.elapsed) when it is out of template.All browser shows special characters correctly.Think it was mvc or Kendo-wrapper related issue.I updated my first message to show how to create listview with MVC razor engine.